# How can I spread the bars of a security gate for a dog?

Tags: gates

I wonder whether anyone can offer me some advice on how to increase the width of my kitchen security gate. By force of habit my five year old Jack Russell as a puppy passed back and forth through the gate into the courtyard without any trouble.

Over time her girth increased substantially, with the result that she manages to exit from the kitchen side of the gate but cannot return.
Would there be any instance that the bars can be stretched or should I employ a welder to remove one of the bars?

I would value your opinion as to he solution.

Later Comments

To all the parties that took the time to 'Drop meo a line'and offered a solution to my Doggy's Dilemma - I thank you - The height of the steel structured gate is 1.94 metres Width 78 cm. 4 bars with increments of between 10. 5cm apart and one of 12cm. Width of bars 7cm. The gate was obviously installed for protection. The courtyard is fully enclosed and leads onto my maid's quarters.

Will have a eelder to remove a bar

Comment: What's the point of the gate if the dog needs to pass through? Please post a photo of the gate using the post editor. Answers will be difficult without seeing its design.

Comment: Will depend on the size of the dog.  A couple of inches and a car jack should do it, but if the size is too big, it will stop keeping other dogs, kids, people out and might as well remove it.

Comment: Opinions are explicitly off-topic here, so asking for them puts you on shaky ground. Please [edit] your question to remove that portion and to add a pic (with a tape measure/ruler so we can get scale) to better understand what you're looking for.

Comment: I like crip659's car jack idea, but you might try this from a recent question: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/267789/79373

Comment: you can get a small bottle jack for $20 from harbor fright.

Comment: So that the dog can but the kid can't? W/e as long as it isn't larger than 4 inches. That's the code for stair blasters so that kids don't get their head stuck. When they die from suffocation, you *will not* be receiving compensation from the gate company as you would have field modified it.